# Two table join query and after date print twig file

Tags: php, symfony, twig

1)  cms

2)  cms_translations

```
cms
id
url
status

cms_translations
object_id
title
lang_id
```

and i have written cmsRepository file

```
    $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT c , d FROM Dashboard\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms c 
    JOIN c.translations d 
    WITH c.id = d.object AND c.status = 1
    GROUP BY c.sortOrder 
    ORDER BY c.sortOrder ASC "
    );
```

and index.html.twing file

```
    {% for entity in enitity_cms %}
    <a href="{{ path('_cmsAboutUs' , { slug : entity.url }) }}" >{{ entity.Title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}    

not print in {{ entity.Title }}
```

How do I print value in html file from second table .

Comment: @benatespina I have rolled back your edit, because you make a change in the code of OP. If there is a typo in the code of OP, point it out in the comments and do not correct it. The typo is possibly the cause of the (or a) problem in the first place! @user2508914 See `enitity_cms` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

try this

{{ entity.translations[0].Title }}

Answer (score 0):

To print the second value:

```
{{ entity.translations.title }}
```

In your exemple:

```
{% for entity in entity_cms %}
    <a href="{{ path('_cmsAboutUs' , { slug : entity.url }) }}" >{{ entity.translations.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this help you